# Get size in latitude/longitude degrees from the current boundaries given a MKMapView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mapkit

The apple developer documentation talks about ["map points"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmaprect/1452453-init) when it comes to get the visible portion of the map that is currently displayed.

What is a map point? how does it relates to latitude/longitude degrees?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmappoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### What is a map point?

> From the [MKMapPoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmappoint) docs -
>
> If you project the curved surface of the globe onto a flat surface, what you get is a two-dimensional version of a map where longitude lines appear to be parallel. Such maps are often used to show the entire surface of the globe all at once. **An `MKMapPoint` data structure represents a point on this two-dimensional map.**
>
> **The actual units of a map point are tied to the underlying units used to draw the contents of an `MKMapView`, but you should never need to worry about these units directly.** You use map points primarily to simplify computations that would be complex to do using coordinate values on a curved surface. By converting to map points, you can perform those calculations on a flat surface, which is generally much simpler, and then convert back as needed. **You can map between coordinate values and map points using the `init(_:)` and coordinate functions.**
>
> **When saving map-related data to a file, you should always save coordinate values (latitude and longitude) and not map points.**

##### How does it relate to latitude/longitude degrees?

> You can create a new `MKMapPoint` instance by using `CLLocationCoordinate2D` value(which can be created using `latitude` & `longitude` values.) See - [MKMapPoint.init(_ coordinate:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmappoint/1452514-init)

---

For `get the visible portion of the map that is currently displayed` part, you can ask `MKMapView` instance about this information using -

1. [MKMapView.region](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452709-region)
2. [MKMapView.visibleMapRect](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452732-visiblemaprect)

---

#### UPDATE

Here's how you can calculate min/max values for `latitude` & `longitude`.

```
let region = mapView.region
let center = region.center
let span = region.span
let minLatitude = (center.latitude - span.latitudeDelta/2)
let maxLatitude = (center.latitude + span.latitudeDelta/2)
let minLongitude = (center.longitude - span.longitudeDelta/2)
let maxLongitude = (center.longitude + span.longitudeDelta/2)
```

Comment: visibleMapRect gives me [height and width](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapsize) in "map points" but I'd like latitude and longitude degrees.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT That's why I mentioned [MKMapView.region](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1452709-region) as the first option. See the **UPDATE**.